# Wifi in hotel for 150 users

Tags: wireless-networking

So curreently I have a bit problem with my WiFi network.

Let me describe a bit:

1. Switches: Tp-link, Dlink unmanagable.
2. Access points : Few Unifi AP-LR and others are tp-links.
3. Router: Tplink N750
4. Fiber convertor: Tp-link.

This is my network in general. Toplogy in one sentence will be like this;
fiber cable - fiber convertor- router - swithes-ap

Problem is my WiFi network is simply dying sometimes. Can't ping anything, even router. But if I connect to the switch by LAN cable and go to static IP of AP I will reach it without any problem.  LAN  works perfectly with 35 ping to 8.8.8.8

So I changed channels so any of them won't collide, and tried to lower transmit power.  Didn't work for me.

Any advices?

Comment: I really wouldn't advise using consumer-grade TP-Link or D-Link equipment for a network that big. You should replace it with some proper managed enterprise networking equipment -- Ubiquiti kit should be fine, and inter-operable with your existing Unifi APs.

Comment: As @MikeScott said, consumer-grade equipment isn't designed for a big network and it's probably the reason the network dies, can't handle the throttle properly..

Comment: Agreed with everyone - You should not use consumer-grade equipment for large user deployments.  Enterprise-Grade Access Points are usually tested to allow for dense client operation.  Try RiverBed's Xirrus APs, Aerohive, Ruckus, Aruba etc.  Are you on 2.4GHz or 5GHz or both?

Answer (score 5):

You have a hotel for 150 users and you use junk AP equipment (802.11n in 2018)?   Spend the money and get an expert and appropriate gear (Drop the tp-link stuff for a start and replace with something like Ubiquity gear - deploy AP's in an appropriate 3 channel separation pattern with appropriate mesh.

Note that its not enough to make sure you have different channels - you need to have NON-OVERLAPPING channels - so you are limited to about 3 of them which you need to repeat in an appropriate pattern.

Assuming doing it properly is not an option - replace the firmware on the router with dd-wrt - it sounds very much like you are running into connection tracking limitations, and dd-wrt is likely better in this regard (t[plink routers are generally limited to 32 simultaneous connections](https://kb.netgear.com/24043/How-many-clients-can-you-connect-wirelessly-to-a-NETGEAR-router)).

Also check your DHCP allocation range is large enough to handle all your users.